# Connection between Android and AppEngine! Suggestions

Tags: android, google-app-engine, gwt, communication

I'm about to start a new project where an android client and a gwt client has to communicate with an appengine server.

My first thougts were
GWT to Appengine = RPC
Android to Appengine = RPC
Appengine to Android = C2DM

My question is if you have better ideas to solve a communication. Basically what I want to do is send some Strings from the GWT client to Appengine and from Appengine to Android and the same way back. But everything for one account. So Bob is signed up on the GWT client and communicates with his Android phone.(should work on 3G too)

Some suggestions?

Comment: There's lots of questions on SO about interfacing Android and App Engine. What do you need to know that isn't covered by them?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Looks like you're looking for RequestFactory: http://googlewebtoolkit.blogspot.com/2011/05/android-meet-app-engine-app-engine-meet.html

It won't solve your "AppEngine to Android" communication though (though maybe you could make it like AppEngine is an RF client and the Android phone an RF server, using CD2M as the [transport](http://google-web-toolkit.googlecode.com/svn/javadoc/latest/com/google/gwt/requestfactory/shared/RequestTransport.html))

Comment: That's the same i wrote... I was looking for alternatives RequestFactory = RPC